# Not able to view files on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I created some files on my HDFS. I was able to execute the hadoop fs -ls command to view them and it worked fine. Later I was not able to view them. Hence I tried to format the namenode and add the files back in and it says the files already exits. Any idea why this is happening? How can I delete the files if I am not able to view them ?

[image]

I was able to view the files on the browser.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be logged in as the user `yeshwanthvenkatesh`. When you run `hadoop fs -ls` with no path, hadoop shows you the contents of your home directory (probably `/user/yeshwanthvenkatesh`) which appears to be empty.  You can try running:

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/scolopax/input/ebird/autogen
```

but since that directory belongs to the user `hadoop`, you likely don't have permissions.  If not, try this:

```
sudo -u hadoop hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop/scolopax/input/ebird/autogen
```